# Is it feature or human doing this?

Tags: discussion

I recently had one strange experience.

I and 2 more users had answered a question and all of sudden all answers were down voted.

[filter product collection by a comma-separated attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105315/filter-product-collection-by-a-comma-separated-attribute)

I then noticed that someone had marked as duplicate.

I then doubt that it might be feature that, if someone marks a qst as duplicate then all answers penalised.

**My Question**

I personally don't think this is a feature, but if it is then how can a user find out whether it is duplicate before answering it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely human.
There is no trigger (that I know of) that would downvote the answers to a question that is subject to closing, because that does not make sense.
There are a lot of other questions marked as duplicate and this does not happen.

And to answer your question...how can you find out if it's a duplicate or not?... at the top of the page on the right side, there is a search functionality. Use it.
You can also google it. The questions from the stackexchange network are nicely indexed by Google.